# Is it possible to access local wordpress site from another computer on the local network?

Tags: apache-http-server, wordpress

What the title states - I have an apache installation listening at port 81. Is there a way to access this from another computer? I'm curious if this sort of thing is possible.

Comment: You’ll need to be more clear about the problem. Are you trying to access the document files (e.g., `http://192.168.1.2/index.html`), or the server files (e.g., `c:\apache\docroot\index.html`)? Are you using local IPs (e.g., `192.168.1.2`) or domain names (e.g., `sheerst.com`)? The answer to all scenarios is potentially yes with the right effort and steps, but what have you tried? What exactly is the problem? Is it slow? What do you mean by “low res”? Add a screenshot to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access it by going to http://`<wordpress host ip address>`:81.

Comment: Yes, it seems like that sort of works. For some reason apache responds with a very 'low-res' version of the page - just text, no images. Not sure why this is.

Comment: Make sure you have set the proper permissions for /var/www.

Answer (score 0):

**It is absolutely possible** : I do it all the time.Check out the following images .

[image]

[image]

Do it as you would for other sites.Just not forget to put the IP of the host machine in the address bar of the browser and navigate to Wordpress.*Also , make sure apache is up and running*.